# Custom slide to unlock component in react native not moving in opposite direction

Tags: react-native, react-native-animatable

I was trying to edit a module source code which is as follows:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';    
import {View, PanResponder, Animated} from 'react-native';
    
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

export default class Slider extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.canReachEnd = true;
    this.totalWidth = 0;
    this.state = {
      offsetX: new Animated.Value(0),
      squareWidth: 0,
      childOpacity: 1,
    };
    this._panResponder = PanResponder.create({
      onStartShouldSetPanResponder: (evt, gestureState) => {
        return true;
      },
      onStartShouldSetPanResponderCapture: (evt, gestureState) => true,
      onMoveShouldSetPanResponder: (evt, gestureState) => {
        return !this.canReachEnd;
      },
      onMoveShouldSetPanResponderCapture: (evt, gestureState) => {
        return true;
      },
      onPanResponderGrant: (evt, gestureState) => {
        this.canReachEnd = true;
      },
      onPanResponderMove: (evt, gestureState) => {
        const margin = this.totalWidth - this.state.squareWidth * 1.025;
        if (this.props.isLeftToRight === true) {
          if (gestureState.dx <= 0) {
            this.setState({
              offsetX: new Animated.Value(gestureState.dx),
              childOpacity: 1 - gestureState.dx / margin,
            });
          } else if (gestureState.dx > 0 && gestureState.dx <= margin) {
            this.setState({
              offsetX: new Animated.Value(gestureState.dx),
              childOpacity: 1 - gestureState.dx / margin,
            });
          } else if (gestureState.dx > margin) {
            this.setState({childOpacity: 0});
            this.onEndReached();
            return;
          }
        } else {
          if (gestureState.dx < -margin) {
            this.setState({childOpacity: 0});
            this.onEndReached();
            return;
          } else if (gestureState.dx > -margin && gestureState.dx < 0) {
            this.setState({
              offsetX: new Animated.Value(-gestureState.dx),
              childOpacity: 1 - -gestureState.dx / margin,
            });
          } else if (gestureState.dx <= 0) {
            this.setState({
              offsetX: new Animated.Value(-gestureState.dx),
              childOpacity: 1 - -gestureState.dx / margin,
            });
          }
        }
      },
      onPanResponderTerminationRequest: (evt, gestureState) => true,
      onPanResponderRelease: (evt, gestureState) => {
        this.resetBar();
        this.canReachEnd = true;
      },
      onShouldBlockNativeResponder: (evt, gestureState) => true,
    });
  }

  onEndReached = () => {
    this.canReachEnd && this.props.onEndReached();
    this.canReachEnd = false;
    this.resetBar();
  };

  resetBar() {
    Animated.timing(this.state.offsetX, {
      toValue: 0,
      useNativeDriver: true,
    }).start();
    this.setState({childOpacity: 1, offsetX: new Animated.Value(0)});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View
        onLayout={event => {
          this.totalWidth = event.nativeEvent.layout.width;
        }}
        style={[
          this.props.containerStyle,
          {
            alignItems:
              this.props.isLeftToRight === true ? 'flex-start' : 'flex-end',
          },
        ]}>
        <Animated.View
          onLayout={event => {
            this.setState({squareWidth: event.nativeEvent.layout.width});
          }}
          style={[
            {transform: [{translateX: this.state.offsetX}]},
            this.props.slideOverStyle,
          ]}
          {...this._panResponder.panHandlers}>
          {this.props.thumbElement}
        </Animated.View>

        <View
          style={[
            {
              alignSelf: 'center',
              position: 'absolute',
              zIndex: -1,
              opacity:
                this.props.isOpacityChangeOnSlide === true
                  ? this.state.childOpacity
                  : 1,
            },
            this.props.childrenContainer,
          ]}>
          {this.props.children}
        </View>

        <View
          style={[
            {
              alignSelf:
                this.props.isLeftToRight === true ? 'flex-start' : 'flex-end',
              position: 'absolute',
              width: this.state.offsetX._value,
              height: 100,
            },
            this.props.slideOverStyle,
          ]}></View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

Slider.propTypes = {
  isLeftToRight: PropTypes.bool,
  childrenContainer: PropTypes.object,
  containerStyle: PropTypes.object,
  slideOverStyle: PropTypes.object,
  isOpacityChangeOnSlide: PropTypes.bool,
  thumbElement: PropTypes.element,
  onEndReached: PropTypes.func,
};

Slider.defaultProps = {
  isLeftToRight: true,
  childrenContainer: {},
  containerStyle: {},
  slideOverStyle: {
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.0)',
    borderBottomLeftRadius: 0,
    borderBottomRightRadius: 0,
    borderTopLeftRadius: 0,
    borderTopRightRadius: 0,
  },
  isOpacityChangeOnSlide: false,
  thumbElement: (
    <View style={{width: 50, height: 50, backgroundColor: 'green'}} />
  ),
  onEndReached: () => {},
};
```

The component is used in a screen like so:

```
<Slider
        isLeftToRight={barrierState === 'closed' ? true : false} // set false to move slider Right to Left
        childrenContainer={{backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.0)'}}
        onEndReached={changeBarrierState}
        isOpacityChangeOnSlide={true}
        containerStyle={styles.sliderContainer}
        thumbElement={
          barrierState === 'closed' ? <SwipeArrowRight /> : <SwipeArroLeft />
        }>
        <Text style={styles.insideText}>Open the Parking Barrier</Text>
      </Slider>
```

But the issue is that the thumbElement is not sliding in right to left direction when isLeftToRight prop is made false. It is moving from the end of the container to further right.

Here is the image for reference of the implementation:
[image: Slide from right to left]

Comment: Just rotate the component 180º on the screen. Then you will also rotate the text in 180º. If you don't rotate the text, it will be upside down.